Make branch name dynamic on Jenkins build pipeline from SCM
I am setting up a Jenkins pipeline which gets triggered when I push a commit. I am having to use Pipeline script from SCM for this purpose where I am having to dynamically set the name of the branch in the field Branch Specifier (blank for 'any').
How do I make the entry generic as the push can come from any branch. I tried leaving it blank but when I build the pipeline, it defaults to a different branch which is not desired.
My current pipeline script looks something like this
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Step 1') {
            steps {
                checkout poll: false, scm: scmGit(
                    branches: [[name: scm.branches[0].name ]],
                    extensions: [submodule(parentCredentials: true, recursiveSubmodules: true, reference: '')],
                    userRemoteConfigs: [[
                        credentialsId: 'xxxxx',
                        url: 'https://github.com/xxx/xxx.git'
                    ]]
                )

            }
        }
        .. more stages
    }
}

I am setting the branch name at the checkout step but on the Build but from SCM GUI seems like I will have to supply the branch name as well as shown in the image.

I am supplying a $GIT_BRANCH env variable but dont know where to set it as it cannot be set on the Jenkinsfile since the checkout is done before. Some help would be appreciated.

If you want each branch to be built separately, then you should go for a multi-branch pipeline. Configure it to point at your GitHub organization and set the "Discover branches" strategy to "All branches". Then run the "Scan organization" option once and it should automatically detect your repo as well as all the branches inside the repo (as long as they have a Jenkinsfile in them. You can then build each one of these branches one by one. Read more in the docs.

yes I used the multibranch option and it worked for me. Thanks!
